# Creating a database of receipts

Tags: mysql, mariadb, postman

I keep getting errors when I try to GET or POST using Postman. The error keeps saying that my table "receipt" does not exist. I cannot determine what is wrong with the code. The code is meant to be used to add data of receipts, so they can be later used to generate a list in android studio.

This is the code I have:

This is the MySql file:
`

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
USE my_database;

CREATE TABLE receipt(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,          /* receipt id */
    name varchar(30) not null,      /* store name */
    total float(5,2) not null,      /* receipt total */
    date date not null,             /* date of purchase */
    time time not null,             /* time of purchase */ 
    Primary Key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  receipt_id INT NOT NULL,          /* foreign key linking to the receipt table */
  item_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  item_price FLOAT(5,2) NOT NULL,
  item_quantity INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (receipt_id) REFERENCES receipt(id)
);

UPDATE receipt
SET total = (SELECT SUM(item_price*item_quantity) FROM items WHERE receipt_id = Receipt.id)`
```

This is a javascript file, index.js:

```
`// We now import the connection object we exported in db.js.
const db = require("../controllers/db");

// More libraries…
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json()); // Automatically parse all POSTs as JSON.
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Automatically parse URL parameters

// Add a new receipt
router.post("/addreceipt", function (req, res) {
    let receipt = req.body;
    let sql = `INSERT INTO receipt (name, total, date, time) VALUES ('${receipt.name}', ${receipt.total}, '${receipt.date}', '${receipt.time}')` ;
    db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
    } else {
    let returnedObject = {
    message: "receipt added successfully"
    };
    return res.json(returnedObject);
    }
    });
    });


// Get all receipts
router.get("/get-receipt/:id", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM receipt WHERE id = ?`;
    db.query(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
    console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
    if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
    } else {
    let returnedObject = {
    receipt: result[0]
    };
    return res.json(returnedObject);
    }
    });
    });
    
    


// Get items of specific receipt
router.get("/get-items/:receipt_id", function (req, res) {
    let receipt_id = req.params.receipt_id;
    let sql = `
        SELECT * FROM items WHERE receipt_id = ${receipt_id}
    `;
    db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            let returnedObject = {
                items: result
            };
            return res.json(returnedObject);
        }
    });
});

// Add item to receipt
    router.post("/add-item", function (req, res) {
    let item = req.body;
    let sql = ` 
    INSERT INTO items (receipt_id, item_name, item_price, item_quantity)
    VALUES (${item.receipt_id}, '${item.item_name}', ${item.item_price}, ${item.item_quantity})
    `;
    db.query
    (sql, function (err, result) {
        console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            let updateTotal = `UPDATE receipt SET total = (SELECT SUM(item_price*item_quantity) FROM items WHERE receipt_id = ${item.receipt_id})`;
            db.query(updateTotal, function(err, result){
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(err);
                }
            });
            let returnedObject = {
                message: "Item added successfully"
            };
            return res.json(returnedObject);
        }
    });
});


// Hello World
router.get("/health", function (req, res) {
    return res.send("ok"); // For plain text, use res.send
});

// Export the created router
module.exports = router;
`
```

Another javascript file, db.js:

```
`// Importing the mysql library:
//
// Similar to import in Java, however, you can name the library object whatever
// you want on the left hand side.
// I recommend you `const` all your imports.
const mysql = require("mysql");

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "my_database"
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Failed to connect to database- throwing error:");
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Connected to database succesfully.");
});

// Each Javascript file has an optional export. This export can be anything: here I made the connection object the export.
module.exports = connection;`
```

Comment: Please add the original error message but also information about MariaDB server version and the operating system on which the server is running.

Comment: Mixing uppercase and lower case for identifiers is always a bad idea: Depending on your configuration and operating system `receipt` and `Receipt` are not the same but different tables.

Comment: @GeorgRichter {
    "code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
    "errno": 1146,
    "sqlMessage": "Table 'my_database.receipt' doesn't exist",
    "sqlState": "42S02",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM receipt WHERE id = ':id'"
}

Comment: @GeorgRichter Fixed the differences between the Receipt and receipt, but still gives  the same error